# How to use callback method in Extjs combobox when queryMode is remote

Tags: extjs, combobox

I am using a combobox which has queryMode:’remote’ ,store:’MyStore and minChars:3.In the controller,I listen to the ‘change’ event as follows:

```
 change: function(combo){
 comboStore = combo.getStore();
 comboProxy = comboStore.getProxy();
 comboProxy.url = ‘http://…..’(url to fetch the data)
```

And on entering the 3rd character,there is a REST call ansd the comboStore gets loaded dynamically.But I need to have a callback method like follows:

```
comboStore.load({
scope:this,
callback:function(record,operation,success){
 }
 });
```

If I explicitly load the store as above,there is a REST call on entering the 1st character also,which I don’t want.Is there any way to achieve this…ie a callback method to load the store and REST call on entering the 3rd character.Any help is highly appreciated..Thanks

Comment: I do not see the reason why would you want all this, please explain. Btw, setting url in change listener does not trigger the load. I is the third character typed.

Comment: actually i want an handle to the operation object which will have the response /responseText/status,so that i check if any error has occurred using status.